# How does Mercurial tell a file was modified?

Tags: mercurial

How does Mercurial tell a file was modified?

The reason I am asking is because when I run `hg status` its telling me several files are modified.
However, when I run `hg diff` there are no changes to report.

I have a theory as why this is happening: (*but I am not positive*)

I am using NetBeans which has Mercurial support built in. When I edit a file, it shows it as modified, although if I undo (rather than revert) those changes and save it, NetBeans tells me there are no local changes. So I am guessing NetBeans uses **diffs** to check for modifications while Mercurial is using something else like *modification-date*.

Is this correct or is something else the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial does not use modification date to determine the status.  This can be verified with a simple experiment:

```
hg init
echo "This is a test" > test.txt
hg commit -Am "commit"
touch test.txt
hg status
```

The code which performs the status check is in [`dirstate.py`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/bf85c2639700/mercurial/dirstate.py#l635).  If the `dirstate` is unsure about a file's status (e.g. because only the modification time differs, then it passes it up to `localrepo.status` for further analysis as seen [here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/bf85c2639700/mercurial/localrepo.py#l1194).

The [`hg help status`](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/status) text has some clues that may help:

> status may appear to disagree with
>   diff if permissions have changed or a
>   merge has occurred. The standard diff
>   format does not report permission
>   changes and diff only reports changes
>   relative to one merge parent.

When you run `hg diff`, are you specifying any command-line options?

Comment: I tried `hg diff` alone, and I tried `hg diff <file>` thats all though.

Comment: @John try diff --git, maybe it is a permission change.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible the permissions of the file changed?  Try `hg diff --git` which shows the git-style extended diffs that support permissions and binaries.  By default `hg diff` shows only patch-friendly diffs, which don't show permissions changes.